# JavaScript doesn't like hashes.to_json?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

In my controller:

```
@arr = []
@jsonPosts = Post.each do |p|
  arrLatLng = {}
  arrLatLng["latitude"] = p.lat
  arrLatLng["longitude"] = p.lon
  @arr << arrLatLng
end 
@postsLatLng = @arr.to_json
```

When I use `console.log(<%= @postsLatLng %>)`, in the view I get an unexpected token and error and it shows:

```
console.log([{&quot;latitude&quot;:34.0462002,&quot;longitude&quot;:-118.2044673},{&quot;latitude&quot;:34.0462074,&quot;longitude&quot;:-118...
```

It works when I change `arrLatLng` to an array:

```
arrLatLng = []
arrLatLng << p.lat
arrLatLng << p.lon
```

I'm wondering:

1. What's the fix?
2. Why does this work when I change `arrLatLng` to an array?

Answer (score 2):

Try http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-j

`console.log(<%= j @postsLatLng %>)`

Also, totally unrelated, but you could do this instead:

```
@postsLatLng = Post.inject([]) { |memo, p|
  memo << {latitude: p.lat, longitude: p.lon}
}.to_json
```

Comment: cool that's definitely a nice refactor. any idea why this is still failing?

Comment: What do you mean when you say it didn't work? It couldn't find the `j` method? Because your JS isn't having its quotes escaped and I'm 99.999% sure that's the issue.

Comment: console.log([{\&quot;latitude\&quot;:34.0462002,\&quot;longitude\&quot;:-118.2044673},{\&quot;latitude\&quot;:34.0462074,\&quot;lon        do I need to include anything to be able to use the j method?

Comment: I don't think so. Replace `console.log(<%= @postsLatLng %>)` with `console.log(<%= j @postsLatLng %>)` in your view.

Comment: yeah, tried that. =/ and curious on your refactor why I'm getting this undefined method `inject' for Post:Class, should I be calling it on something else?

Comment: I changed it to console.log(<%= @postsLatLng.html_safe %>) and it worked!

Comment: This is seriously confusing me and I can't find out what is going wrong.  Despite that console log working, I define the variable below as var loc = <%= @postsLatLng.html_safe %> but I got a new error that said call stack too deep.  I really don't think this is such unique issue - sending hashes to javascript - but can't seem figure this out.  Thanks for your help kaleidoscope